# I can't print a variable on console

Tags: c#

I am learning C# and I wrote below code but I am unable to print the name on console. Can any one tell me why?

```
 public class BaseClass
{
    public String Name;

    public void Print()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Name is:", Name);

    }

}
class PublicDemo
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();
        Console.Write("Enter your Name:");
        bc.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
        bc.Print();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the behaviour your are seeing?

Comment: @SelectDistinct That still won't print the name

Comment: You should start your variables with lowercase, and keep uppercase for methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you don't have a format parameter in your `WriteLine` call:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name is:{0}", Name);
// Name is:user1794624
```

You can do lots:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name three times: {0} {0} {0}, followed by three {1}", Name, 3);
// Name three times: user1794624 user1794624 user1794624, followed by three 3
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name is: {0}", Name);
```

`Console.Write Method (String, Object[])` works like `String.Format`.

> This method uses the composite formatting feature of the .NET
>   Framework to convert the value of an object to its text representation
>   and embed that representation in a string. The resulting string is
>   written to the output stream.
>
> The format parameter consists of zero or more runs of text intermixed
>   with zero or more indexed placeholders, called format items, that
>   correspond to an object in the parameter list of this method. The
>   formatting process replaces each format item with the text
>   representation of the value of the corresponding object.
>
> The syntax of a format item is {index[,alignment][:formatString]},
>   which specifies a mandatory index, the optional length and alignment
>   of the formatted text, and an optional string of format specifier
>   characters that govern how the value of the corresponding object is
>   formatted.

[Console.Write MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttxecb1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[String.Format MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Any explanation would be welcome. Just a code fix won't help OP.

Answer (score 2):

The line `Console.Write("Enter your Name:");` is the problem. It will never print the value or your variable `Name`, because you didn't included it in the [overload of Console.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xdyw6yk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The `Console.Write Method (String, Object[])` has the same behavior of the method [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Indeed the line `Console.Write("Enter your Name: {0}", Name);` has the same output of

```
Console.Write(String.Format("Enter your Name: {0}",Name));
```

Use then:

```
Console.Write("Enter your Name: {0}", Name);
```

or

```
Console.Write("Enter your Name: " + Name);
```

or

```
Console.Write(String.Format("Enter your Name: {0}",Name));
```